# Problem with spaces in property file with Spring Boot 2.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, keystore

I started having issues reading keystore after I updated my spring boot version from 2.0.2 to 2.1.2 and tomcat from 9.0.7 to 9.0.14.

Everything was working perfectly. Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type [PKCS12 ] with path [jar:file:/home/landing/landing.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keystore.p12] due to [PKCS12  not found]
```

And what I've noticed so far is there is an **exclamation point** that I think it should not be there, right before the filename.
The config is the following and the actual file is inside the Jar file.

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
```

Any ideas, besides going back to the previous versions?

**EDIT: I've rolled back to Spring Boot 2.0.3. The problem started happening from version 2.0.4 and above. It is not related to Tomcat.**

**EDIT 2: I'm using Java 8 and it might been related to adding support to other Java versions.**

Comment: It isn't due to that the file cannot be found. But something is wrong with initializing the specific type of keystore.

Comment: The file is there. I've decided to roll back the versions. It is NOT tomcat. It's Spring Boot. I've tested several versions so far.

Comment: Make sure you have all the properties set and that also the root certificates are included. It finds the file else you would get a different message...

Comment: The exclamation point is (correctly) part of the syntax for `jar:` URLs; it separates the name of the jar from the name of the entry in the jar. From that error message it looks to me like something is specifying the keystore _type_ as "PKCS12(space)" or maybe "PKCS12(weird char that doesn't display)" instead of just "PKCS12".

Comment: I've detected an space in the config file. I will update the dependencies and check...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of dave_thompson_085 (Thanks!!!!!) I was able to resolve it.

Apparently there was a change between versions 2.0.3 and 2.0.4 in regard to the hanlding of blank spaces in property files.

Up to 2.0.3 I think the spaces were trimmed.

From 2.0.4 Spring stopped trimming the spaces and read them as part of the value.

There were blank spaces in 2 fields which caused Spring to throw weird errors.